# Interrupted quotation in a paragraph

Tags: capitalization, writing, quotations, dialogue, quoting

Please help me with the correct usage of capitalisation in an interrupted quotation.

For example:

> Alice yelled, "Get out of here."

In the above sentence, the first word under the quotes is capitalised as it's a complete sentence. But what happens in case of an interrupted quotation here? I mean what if the sentence was like,

> Alice yelled, "Get out of here," pointing to the door, "I can't handle you right now."

In this sentence is it correct to capitalised the first letter of the quoted sentence.

Ps: I know many of you would suggest that to end the sentence at the word "door". But this is just an example. I want to understand the rule here.

Comment: In the second example 'I' is always going to be capitalised anyway.

Comment: Your suggestion of introducing a full-stop is definitely the best thing to do. Using a comma will almost certainly create a run-on sentence, as indeed it does in your example.

Comment: @KillingTime I'm asking about the word "get". Should it be capitalised or not in the second example.

Comment: @Andrew Leach it's in this sentence, but what's the general rule here. In the second example, "Get out of here," is a part of a full sentence, which is being interrupted by the author's words. So the first word under the quotation here should be capitalised here or not.

Comment: The first word of Alice's speech should of course be capitalised. If you choose to interrupt her mid-sentence, the second half of the sentence would not normally start with a capital letter. It does in your example because it begins with 'I'.

Comment: You have answered your own question: "the first word under the quotes is capitalised as it's a complete sentence." However, it's not capitalised because it's a complete sentence; a capital letter always appears at the start of any sentence, whether or not it's completed. Relevant and possibly a duplicate: [Edge cases](/questions/73216).

Comment: Thank you @Andrew Leach. I see your point and agree with them. However, in quoted sentences, incomplete sentences are not supposed to start with a capital letter. I was just curious to know whether an interrupted quote is considered as a complete sentence or not.

Comment: Thank you @Kate Bunting for your answer. I will keep that in mind.